# Does the same floating-point calculation producing different results when performed twice indicate IEEE 754 non-conformance?

Tags: c++, floating-point, ieee-754

In a specific online judge running 32-bit GCC 7.3.0, this:

```
#include <iostream>

volatile float three = 3.0f, seven = 7.0f;

int main()
{
    float x = three / seven;
    std::cout << x << '\n';
    float y = three / seven;
    std::cout << (x == y) << '\n';
}
```

Outputs

```
0.428571
0
```

To me this seems like it violates IEEE 754, since the standard requires basic operations to be correctly rounded. Now I know there are a couple reasons for IEEE 754 floating-point calculations to be non-deterministic as discussed [here](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/floating-point-determinism/), but I don't see how any of them applies to this example. Here are some of the things I considered:

- Excess precision and contraction: I'm doing a single calculation and assigning the result to a `float`, which should force both of the values to be rounded to `float` precision.
- Compile-time calculations: `three` and `seven` are `volatile` so both calculations must be done at runtime.
- Floating-point flags: The calculations are done in the same thread almost immediately after each other, so the flags should be the same.

Does this necessarily indicate that the online judge system doesn't conform to IEEE 754?

Also, removing the statement printing `x`, adding a statement to print `y`, or making `y` volatile all changes the result. This seems to contradict my understanding of the C++ standard which I think requires the assignments to round off any excess precision.

Thanks to geza for pointing out that this is a [known issue](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=323). I would still like a definitive answer on whether this conforms to the C++ standard and IEEE 754 though, since the C++ standard appears to require assignments to round off excess precision. Here's the quote from draft N4860 [expr.pre]:

> The values of the floating-point operands and the results of floating-point expressions may be represented in greater precision and range than that required by the type; the types are not changed thereby.<sup>50</sup>
>
> 50) The cast and assignment operators must still perform their specific conversions as described in 7.6.1.3, 7.6.3, 7.6.1.8 and 7.6.19.

Comment: "_online judge_" ... well, do you control how the online judge compiles the programs? fast-math-options may mess with floats. The compiler does something else @ [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/90tWrY)

Comment: @TedLyngmo As far as I know this online judge doesn't use any fast math options. `std::numeric_limits<float>::is_iec559` is true. `__FAST_MATH__` is not defined.

Comment: I added the fast-math options @ godbolt but still got the correct result. Try using an offline compiler and see what you get.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yeah I haven't been able to reproduce this anywhere else. Does this mean the judge is not IEEE 754 conforming then?

Comment: It's certainly a possibility.

Comment: @BessieTheCow -- This is why online judge questions that require floating point are the ones to stay away from.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I totally agree with that.

Comment: It can be easily reproduced. The key is to use the FPU, and use optimization. So comparison will be done between a 32-bit float and 80-bit FPU register. (just add the option `-m32` at Ted's link)

Comment: @geza Doesn't the C++ standard require the assignment to round the value to float precision? Draft N4860 states in [expr.pre] "The values of the floating-point operands and the results of floating-point expressions may be represented in greater precision and range than that required by the type; the types are not changed thereby." but the footnote of that part states "The cast and assignment operators must still perform their specific conversions as described in 7.6.1.3, 7.6.3, 7.6.1.8 and 7.6.19."

Comment: This is a long-standing issue. gcc has the option `-ffloat-store` which fixes the issue. Or you can generate code, which uses SSE instead of FPU. I know one thing for almost-sure: this issue won't be fixed in gcc (as there were a **lot** of bug reports about this in the past: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=323).

Comment: Maybe one of the division was performed at compile time and the other was done at execution time and the fpu was set to a rounding mode that is not the one used by gcc at compile time. Such surprising behavior is explicitly accepted in the standard: http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#12

Comment: @Oliv: The implementation in question purports to conform to IEC 559 (it reports true for `std::numeric_limits<float>::is_iec559`), so evaluations during compilation and execution should not differ. The fact there is a difference but `is_iec559` is true indicates a bug in the compiler. And the reproduction by adding `-m32` at the given [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/90tWrY) shows the compiler is evaluating using the Intel 80-bit floating-point format and converting one operand of the `==` to 64-bit but not the other.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I missed this. Does iec559 impose any rounding mode? If not GCC is not wrong, it is just an execution issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this necessarily indicate that the online judge system doesn't conform to IEEE 754?

Yes, with minor caveats.

One, C++ cannot just “conform” to IEEE 754. There has to be some specification of how things in C++ bind (connect) to IEEE 754, such as statements that the `float` format is IEEE-754 binary32, that `x / y` uses IEEE-754 division, and so on. C++ 2017 draft N4659 refers to LIA-1, but I do not see that it clearly requires LIA-1 be used even if `std::numeric_limits<float>::is_iec559` reports true, and LIA-1 [apparently only suggests language bindings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_10967).

The C++ standard tells us the fact that `std::numeric_limits<float>::is_iec559` reports true means the `float` type conforms to ISO/IEC/IEEE 60559, which is effectively IEEE 754-2008. But, in addition to the binding problem, I do not see a statement in the C++ standard that nullifies 8 [expr] 13 (“The values of the floating operands and the results of floating expressions may be represented in greater precision and range than that required by the type; the types are not changed thereby.”) when `is_iec559` is true. Although it is true that the cast and conversion operators must “perform their specific conversions” (footnote 64), and this forces `float y = three / seven;` to produce the correct IEEE-754 binary32 results even if binary64 or Intel’s 80-bit floating-point are used for the division, it might not force it to produce the correct result if only a little excess precision is used. (If at least 48 bits of precision are used, no double-rounding errors occur for division when rounded to the 24-bits of the binary32 format. If fewer excess bits are used, there may be some cases that experience double rounding errors.)

I believe the intent of `is_iec559` is to indicate a sensible binding, and the behavior shown in the question does violate this. In particular, the defect shown in the question is caused by failing to round the excess precision used in the division to the actual `float` type; it is not caused by the hypothetical use of less-than-enough excess precision mentioned above.